# How can I find list of AWS EBS volumes in my account that have size >=200GIB using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ebs

I am executing the command below in AWS CLI to find volumes that have size>=200GIB but the command returns nothing. But from the AWS console I can see that few volumes have a size >=200GiB

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes  --filter "Name=size,Values= >=200GiB"
```

Comment: I've noticed that almost all your questions got answers, yet not a single answer was ever accepted. Accepting helpful answers is not only a good practice, but it reduces the number of duplicates and helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think correct format is

> aws ec2 describe-volumes  --query "Volumes[?Size > `100`].{tag:Tags,ID:VolumeId,size:Size,type:VolumeType}"

Above command is working at my end

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --query 'Volumes[?Size > `250`].[VolumeId,Size]' --output text
```

Comment: I get this error when I execute the command

Comment: C:\Users\Sakshi Gupta>aws ec2 describe-volumes --query 'Volumes[?Size > `250`].[VolumeId,Size]' --output text

Bad value for --query 'Volumes[?Size: Bad jmespath expression: Unclosed ' delimiter:
'Volumes[?Size

Answer (score 0):

the one that really works is the following:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --query "Volumes[?Size > `250`].[VolumeId,Size]" --output table
```